# Any books on design website UI without referring to images?

Tags: user-interface

I'm weak enough in art,so this kind of books will really help me lot,if there is.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more verbose in your question. The title is not very clear, and the rest is not enough to clarify what you really want.

Comment: I want a solution for creating websites without much graphing.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you don't want developers to design graphics and you don't want designers to write code.  Assume you have someone else creating graphics for you (or use one of the many services on the web that do this sort of thing cheaply).  Just use placeholder images while you are learning; i.e. load up mspaint (or gimp or whatever floats your boat) and just make something that you can recognize.

But it is unrealistic to try to do modern webdesign using zero images.  Even with some of the advanced awesomeness of CSS.

Comment: +1 for the services but I would like to point out that StackOverflow is done with minimal images. There is just the logo and the ad's and I think that is about it...

Comment: Indeed, but SO has a very specialized audience.  Images would just get in the way on this site.  I suspect that the little hover buttons next to comments are images (I haven't checked).

Comment: @Frank,do you know how SO achieved this?

Comment: They use CSS and the box model to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by reading this book: [Don't Make Me Think: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)

Comment: Great book, but doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Maybe it's just experience and can only be learned by practice?

Answer (score 2):

No offence, but you can't do website *design* without images, or even without having a strong creative/artistic streak. Now web *development* you can do without any creative talent, and minimal knowledge of CSS. Often the two roles blur, but you're going to have to either work with someone who does the design side, or learn how to do web design - images and all.

Comment: @Draemon,maybe you should look at SO

Comment: SO more or less has no graphic design, which works for an extremely limited number of sites in niche markets. Sure, exceptions exist, but it would be bad advice to suggest that SO-style design works for the majority of sites.